# How to solve fatal error: 'linux/spi/spidev.h' file not found on mac

Tags: macos, cross-compiling, hardware, spi, spidev

I am a newbie. Currently, I am using the terminal on MAC to compile a C code. I encountered the following errors:

> fatal error: 'linux/spi/spidev.h' file not found

Maybe spidev was not installed on my laptop. I am using an Allwinner board. Can anybody help me solve this error? Sorry for my simple question. Is there any way to install spidev (C code) for MAC?"

Comment: So, have you set the cross-compilation tools up?

Comment: @BalajiSivasakthi, have you even read the question?!

Comment: don't understand exactly, it seems like you encountering error with spidev.